# Select the second highest value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I actually try to get the second highest value of a table with this request :

```
SELECT MIN(`mensualite`) AS min, MAX(`mensualite`) AS max FROM `mensualites`
WHERE((`financement` = "1200") 
AND (`mensualite` < ( SELECT MAX(`mensualite`) FROM  `mensualites`)))
```

But unfortunately it still fetch the highest value and not the second. Do you know where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `WHERE` clause also to your subquery

```
SELECT MIN(`mensualite`) AS min, MAX(`mensualite`) AS max FROM `mensualites`
WHERE `financement` = "1200" 
AND `mensualite` < ( SELECT MAX(`mensualite`) FROM  `mensualites` WHERE `financement` = "1200")
```

This assumes that if the maximum occurs twice you want the highest value less than the maximum. If you would like the maximum value in that case you have to use a solution based on ordering.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative method:

```
select mensualite
from (select distinct mensualite
      from mensualites
      WHERE `financement` = "1200"
      order by mensuality desc
      limit 2
     ) m
order by mensuality
limit 1
```

It selects the top two values in the subquery.  Then it orders them ascending and chooses the top row.

This is, however, easier with offset:

```
     select distinct mensualite
      from mensualites
      WHERE `financement` = "1200"
      order by mensuality desc
      limit 1, 1
```

(when using offset, the rows start counting at 0 rather than 1, so "1" means the second row).

Comment: I will use the solution of ptityeti but thank you for your comprehensive answer !